# Save to array an array content that it's inside array

Tags: php

I have this array. I want to extract to a new one array the content of only one of this array ([choices]). How can i do it in php?

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => field_54df3275b708a
            [label] => Idioma
            [name] => idioma
            [type] => select
            [instructions] => 
            [required] => 0
            [choices] => Array
                (
                    [Catalan] => Catalan
                    [Castellano] => Castellano
                    [Ingles] => Ingles
                )

            [default_value] => 
            [allow_null] => 0
            [multiple] => 0
            [conditional_logic] => Array
                (
                    [status] => 0
                    [rules] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [field] => null
                                    [operator] => ==
                                    [value] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [allorany] => all
                )

            [order_no] => 0
        )

)
```

I try this code (i think that's its a bad code):

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
          if (is_array($v)){
            foreach($v as $l=>$w){
                if ($w){ 
                    foreach($w as $s=>$t){
                        $idiomas[]=$t.'<br />';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it saves [choices] and [conditional_logic] to new array, and i only want [choices]

Thankyou so much

Comment: Will the first array have more then one element or do you want the choice of every 'child' array?

Comment: `$new_array_choices = $array[0][choices];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$new_array_choices = $array[0]['choices'];`

Took me awhile to create a [test code fiddle](http://viper-7.com/Ng1BgQ). I had to manually recreate the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you take the key in every foreach all the time, you can use it to ensure it's the array you want :

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
  if (is_array($v)) {
    foreach($v as $l=>$w) {
      if ($w && $l == 'choices') { // $w is the wanted array
        foreach($w as $s=>$t) {
          $idiomas[]=$t.'<br />';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what you are testing with if `($w)` though

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$arr` with your actual array and it should work nonetheless.

```
// your array (replace)
$arr = array(
    "required" => 0,
    "choices" => array(
        "Catalan" => "Catalan",
        "Castellano" => "Castellano",
        "Ingles" => "Ingles",
    ),  
    "default" => NULL,
);

// the empty resulting array
$new_arr = array();

foreach($arr["choices"] as $key)
    array_push($new_arr, $arr["choices"][$key]);

// your resulting array
print_r($new_arr);
```

Your desired array is saved in the array `$new_arr`.